# Web app fails to start: iisexpress.exe has exited with code 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

This occurs on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 with any browser starting with or without debugging:

iisexpress.exe has exited with code 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem, I installed [.Net Core tools preview for Visual Studio](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546).

See the [.NET Core installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015) for how to do this.

Comment: This fixed my problem, even my project was not a .NET Core or something.

Comment: This is good information. I just moved my projects to a windows 10 environment. This saved me after trying many other suggestions. Thanks @eric-schneider.

Comment: Thanks @Justjyde, and I had to fight to keep this question listed. Viewed 6332 times too...